# How does SQL Server Update rows with more than one value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In an update statement for a temp table, how does SQL Server decide which value to use when there are multiple values returned, for example:

```
UPDATE A
SET    A.dte_start_date = table1.dte_start_date
FROM   #temp_table A
INNER JOIN table1 ON A.id = table1.id
```

In this situation the problem is more than one dte_start_date is returned for each id value in the temp table. There is there's no index or unique value in the tables I'm working on so I need to know how SQL Server will choose between the different values.

Comment: I think this is non-deterministic. What behaviour do you want?

Comment: I think you can control this by adding a GROUP BY to the end of the query and select the one you wish (like max, sum, avg etc).

Comment: I believe this is a "feature"/peculiarity of MySQL. Other RDBMS will complain whereas MySQL will pick a random match.

Comment: Hang on, is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @TimSchmelter The rows in the temp table contain items that have actions performed upon them, the dates of these actions are stored in table1. So in the above query trying to get a date that an action was performed upon each item is returning more than one for each line. I wanted to know how SQL chooses which date to update each row with when there are more than one.

Comment: @JohnBarça My mistake SQL server but knowing the differences between different SQL versions wouldn't be a bad thing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is non-deterministic. See the following example for a better understanding. Though it is not exactly the same scenario explained here, it is pretty similar

When the single value is to be retrieved from the database also use the SET statement with a query to set the value.  For example:

```
SET @v_user_user_id = (SELECT u.user_id FROM users u WHERE u.login = @v_login);
```

Reason:  Unlike Oracle, SQL Server does not raise an error if more than one row is returned from a SELECT query that is used to populate variables.  The above query will throw an exception whereas the following will not throw an exception and the variable will contain a random value from the queried table(s).

```
SELECT @v_user_user_id = u.user_id FROM users u WHERE u.login = @v_login;
```

Comment: I believe MySQL will also not complain, whereas Postgres gives a "more than one row returned from subquery" type error.

Answer (score 1):

It is non-deterministic which value is used if you have a one two many relationship.

In MS-SQL-Sever (>=2005) i would use a CTE since it's a readable way to specify what i want using `ROW_NUMBER`. Another advantage of a CTE is that you can change it easily to do a select instead of an update(or delete) to see what will happen.

Assuming that you want the latest record(acc.to `dte_start_date`) for every id:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT a.*, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id 
                                        ORDER BY a.dte_start_date DESC)
    FROM #temp_table A
    INNER JOIN table1 ON A.id = table1.id
)
UPDATE A
SET    A.dte_start_date = table1.dte_start_date
FROM #temp_table A INNER JOIN CTE ON A.ID = CTE.ID
WHERE CTE.RN = 1
```